# How do I specify a pattern constraint using JAXB annotations?

Tags: annotations, xsd, jaxb, constraints

I'm developing a SOAP application using JAX-WS and JAXB. I'd like to specify a pattern constraint for one of the fields (a Dutch postcode, `\d{4}[A-Z]{2}`). That's very easy to do using `xsd:pattern`, but I can't find the equivalent JAXB annotation. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The idea is to use JAXB annotations in combination with runtime validation against the schema, using `javax.xml.validation.Schema`, which can be plugged into the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: +1 - @Sietse for more info checkout:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: +1 since it answers the question. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. This works if I have a schema and want to create Java classes from it. But what if I have Java classes and want to generate a schema (in this case, for inclusion in the WSDL) from it? I'll create a different question, I guess.

Comment: @Sieste - You can use JAXB to create an XML schema (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema), then add in the schema constraints.  And use this schema with the strategy proposed by skaffman.