# how to customize a JAX-WS generated WSDL?

Tags: wsdl, jaxb, jax-ws, customization

I am creating a SOAP service using JAX-WS and JAXB, by annotating the classes. My service implementation looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Local(WSApplicationService.class)
@WebService(name = "WSApplicationService", serviceName = "WSApplicationService")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING)
public class WSApplicationServiceImpl implements WSApplicationService {

  @Override
  @WebMethod
  @WebResult(name = "reference")
  public long submitApplication(@WebParam(name = "application") ApplicationSubmission application) throws SOAPException {
    ...
  }
}
```

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625094/how-do-i-specify-a-pattern-constraint-using-jaxb-annotations), I learned that there's no way to specify certain restrictions on the input data using JAXB annotations. However, I need to restrict certain String properties to patterns (mainly postcodes and phone numbers). Therefore, I'm looking to customize the WSDL generated by above class. I can't find a way to access the WSDL though. Is there a way to override or customize the JAX-WS generated WSDL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can safely have the WSDL generated automatically, it usually makes sense to hand-code the XSD referenced from the WSDL, which gives you all the richness of expression that a schema generated from JAXB classes can't, and also ensures the schema doesn't change when you don't want it to. (This practice is called [contract-first](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html), whereas starting with the classes is called code-first.)

When you do contract-first, you can generate your JAXB classes from the XSD automatically as part of your build process, making sure they're always in sync. You can customize the generated classes using [XJB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) files.

In case you're using Maven, generating the classes could look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <extension>true</extension>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Of course you can also use your hand-coded classes with a hand-coded schema definition (by telling the marshaller where to find it). I don't think you can take influence on the WSDL generation by other means.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know how I can tell the marshaller where to find the schema?

Comment: This will depend on how you initialize JAXB (using Spring-WS, the RI, or something else?), but ultimately, the `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller` and `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` interfaces have a `setSchema()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I honestly have no idea how I initialize JAXB, I just annotate the class and deploy in JBoss AS.